# how to swap columns to rows view

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have following two columns of data in excel 2007:

```
a  1
b  2
...
```

What I need to swap the view to:

```
a  b  ...
1  2  ...
```

I think there is way to do it in excel 2007. Is this possible?

Comment: Not programming related.  However, what you're looking for is a pivot table.  Search for doing pivots in your excel help.

Answer (score 5):

No VBA programming necessary.

Just Copy, Paste Special, then check the "transpose" box.

Comment: that's great. No need to write VBA codes event not hard.